# Printing the contents of a global array using a loop produces no output

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables

I am trying the following code snippet that is supposed to print the contents of the global array. But why is the `for` loop never being entered?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};

int main()
{
    int d;

    for(d = -1; d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++)
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? is `for ( d = 0 ; d < TOTAL_ELEMENTS ; d++ ) ... array[d] ...` too simple?

Comment: How do you know it does not executed? What does the debugger say? The code is obfuscated, but looks ok.

Comment: I guess: d is promoted to unsigned int because of the define is unsigned. Then the -1 became the MAX of unsigned int

Comment: @Olaf "_How do you know it does not executed?_" -- Try running it. You won't get any output.

Comment: @highlander141 Pay attention to the warning. Don't ignore it.

Comment: Yes @CoolGuy I've got it the conversion ;-)

Comment: @CoolGuy: I get a conversion warning. `sizeof` returns `size_t`. Fun with coercion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is promoted to `unsigned int` because of the `#define` of `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is `unsigned`. So, the `-1` becomes the maximum value of `unsigned int`.

Change your code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23, 34, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};

int main()
{
    int d;

    for(d = -1; d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 2); d++)
        printf("%d\n", array[d + 1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On a 64 bit arch, it is likely coerced to `unsigned long`, because `size_t` (returned by `sizeof`) is likely 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I was a little surprised to see that you are right ;-) It seems to be that your for loop parses your macro to an unsigned value, making it unable to correctly compared with a negative integer. Replace the for statement with

```
for(d=-1;d <= ((int)TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
```

and your code works.